# Vagrant upがConnection timeout. Retrying...から進まない

Tags: vagrant

「$ vagrant up」でvccwの立ち上げをやろうとしているのですが、「Connection timeout. Retrying...」から先に進めません。

> $ vagrant up
>   Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>   ==> default: Importing base box 'centos'...
>   ==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
>   ==> default: Setting the name of the VM: vagrant-wataca_default_1435643479833_86344
>   ==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
>   ==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
>   ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
>   ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
>       default: Adapter 1: nat
>   ==> default: Forwarding ports...
>       default: 22 => 2200 (adapter 1)
>   ==> default: Booting VM...
>   ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
>       default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
>       default: SSH username: vagrant
>       default: SSH auth method: private key
>       default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
>       default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying..

その際のエラー文は以下のとおりです。

> Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
>   Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
>   the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.
>
> If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
>   Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
>   are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.
>
> If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
>   working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
>   problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
>   Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
>   as well.
>
> If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
>   the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

config.vm.boot_timeoutを10秒→120秒に書き換えると以下のようなメッセージに変わりました。

> The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
>   to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
>   'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
>   properly and try again.
>
> If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
>   it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
>   GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
>   For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
>   VirtualBox GUI is open.

「vagrant up」後に「vagrant ssh」で接続することもできません。

また他のVagrantfileでも同様の問題が発生していますので、

VirtualBoxまわりかSSHの設定が漏れているのかなと思っていますが、この先どう調べていけばいいのか手詰まり状態です。

かなり基本的なミスではないかと思うのですが、アドバイスを頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

----- こちらに該当する場合は、難しいかもしれません -----

・Nested Virtualizationをやろうとしている
・ゲストで64bitOSを起動しようとしている

VirtualBoxはハードウェア仮想化支援機能が正常に働かないため、
64bitのNested Virtualizationはできないと思います(ゲストOSが32bitなら多分いけます)。
[VirtualBoxでのNested Virtualizationは無理だったという話](http://heroween.hateblo.jp/entry/2014/05/28/125451)

余談ですが、さくらのVPSもvmx・svmはサポートしていないそうです。

----- 上記に該当しないのであれば、こちらで解決するかもしれません -----

[Vagrant で CentOS64bit に ssh 接続出来なかったのを解消](http://sakashushu.blog.so-net.ne.jp/2014-06-16)
[vagrant up起動に失敗したら](http://qiita.com/last-resort/items/21e4456b8318db877f5b)

> VirtualBox GUI is open.

は[3.Vagrantfileをいじる](http://qiita.com/last-resort/items/21e4456b8318db877f5b#3vagrantfile%E3%82%92%E3%81%84%E3%81%98%E3%82%8B)あたりが参考になるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 `VBoxManage list runningvms`で確認したところVirtualBoxは起動している様子でした。ただし`ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222`で直接入ろうとすると、`ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`というエラーが返ってきていますので、ホスト側の問題なのかなと思っています。

Answer (score 1):

出力を見る限りVCCWのバージョンが古いかVCCWではありません。
VCCWは最新版を使ってください。
VirtualBoxとVagrantも最新版がいいです。

さらにいえばVagrantのボックスも以下のコマンドでアップデートしてください。

```
vagrant box update
```

たぶん原因はVagrant 1.7での仕様変更によるものじゃないかと思われます。
https://twitter.com/mitchellh/status/525704126647128064

こういうツールはサードパーティのツールとの依存関係のかたまりなので、なるべく新しいものを使うのがコツだと思います。

Answer (score 1):

普段は問題なかったのに、突然上手く行かなくなったというときの意外な線での可能性では、例えば無線LAN子機等の外部ネットワーク接続デバイスを使っていて同様のことが起きることがあります。
もしそういうものが接続されていたら、一度外してからvagrant up してみると上手く行くかもしれません。
原因としてはゲストOS側のsshdがクライアントの名前解決を行おうとしていることがあり得ます。
[vagrantの本家サイトにも同様の記述](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes/base.html)があります。

> In order to keep SSH speedy even when your machine or the Vagrant machine is not connected to the internet, set the UseDNS configuration to no in the SSH server configuration.
>   This avoids a reverse DNS lookup on the connecting SSH client which can take many seconds.

Answer (score 0):

似たような症状が出て、いろいろはまった結果、私の場合は、Hyper-Vを切ったらうまくいきました。どうも、仮想環境の構築がバッティングしているらしいです。

以下のサイトを参照しました。

[Windows 10 で Hyper-V と Oracle VirtualBox v5.0.0 は両立できない !?](http://app-review.poox.xyz/archives/1449#Hyper-V)